# Behavior of Apache Kafka during Broker failure

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, partition, broker, exporter

We’ve been using Kafka in a 3 broker cluster with about 85 partitions total, most of which are replication factor 3. We’ve also been using a JMX exporter to collect metrics on the cluster.

We noticed lately than when a broker goes down, the “Partition Count” reported in the metrics goes up for the other two nodes.

My understanding is that when a Broker goes down, ISRs will be lost and leaders will be re-elected, but nothing new should be created on the other two Brokers. Any reason why a Broker would report going over 100+ for this metric when another Broker fails?